# Puma is not working on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I have rails 5 app running on my ubuntu 14.04 server on top of nginx. But when I am trying to start the rails app its throwing error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:266:in initialize': Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "example.com" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

Comment: Not a rails geek myself but I'm guessing your computer is not named example.com. Either that or port 3000 is already in use.

Comment: Port is not in use and just for reference I gave example.com in that place I am using my real domain name.

Comment: Ok. can that same system ping the domain name? eg; is DNS resolving the hostname to an IP?

Comment: How do I check that ? I have also feeling that may be something is going wrong over there.

Comment: open a terminal and type `ping hostname` when hostname is the server name used in your code

Comment: It was DNS issue only I fixed that thank you :)

Comment: if you don't mind I will type that as an answer so future people with the same problem can find it. Kindly accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While RAILS is not my area, this sounds like either port 3000 is already in use, or DNS is failing to resolve the hostname `example.com` (which I'm aware is not the actual hostname)

Check that this same system can ping the hostname, which is a quick way to tell if DNS is resolving it. If not, you can make an entry for it in the systems /etc/hosts file